# Schools in a state or of a state?

Tags: grammar

Which is the more appropriate preposition? Of or in?

- This event, held in NYC, reached hundreds of teenagers from public and private schools OF Florida.
- This event, held in NYC, reached hundreds of teenagers from public and private schools IN Florida.

Answer (score 1):

While **of** is possible, **in** suits the context better.

(Your question should be **which is the MORE appropriate preposition** rather than **....the MOST appropriate....**.)

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with [Ronald](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/234701/105169) that, for the sentences you brought, "while **of** is possible, **in** suits the context better."

However, observe that each [preposition](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/preposition/) brings it's own meaning to a sentence. Disregarding your context, `schools of Florida (state)` could restrict the institutions which are under state regency, while `schools in Florida` will be more embracing, including all colleges in the state geographic area.